# How do I take an entire columns worth of data and put it into anther column using a WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I have two extremely similar tables in the same database.  I want to take the entire 'visual' column from the table `p992_cq31n06-cm16-x` and put it into the 'visual' column of the table `p992_cq31n06-cu67-x` where the columns 'print' and 'id3' match up.

Here is the query I was going to run:

```
    UPDATE `p992_cq31n06-cu67-x`
    SET visual = (
        SELECT visual
        FROM `p992_cq31n06-cm16-x`
    WHERE 
        `p992_cq31n06-cu67-x`.print = `p992_cq31n06-cm16-x`.print 
    AND
        `p992_cq31n06-cu67-x`.id3 = `p992_cq31n06-cm16-x`.id3);
```

Is this going to work the way I want it to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your query is going to work the way you want it to.

You can also express this using a `join`:

```
UPDATE `p992_cq31n06-cu67-x` cu67 join
       `p992_cq31n06-cm16-x`cu16
       on cu67.print = cu16.print and cu67.id3 = cu16.id3
    SET cu67.visual = cu16.visual;
```

The `join` is particularly advantageous if you want to set multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

use a join:

```
update p992_cq31n06-cu67-x a 
inner join p992_cq31n06-cm16-x b on a.print = b.print and a.id3 = b.id3
set a.visual = b.visual
```

For MSSQL (Which is what I'd missread the question as!) its

```
update a
set visual = b.visual
from
p992_cq31n06-cu67-x a
inner join p992_cq31n06-cm16-x b on a.print = b.print and a.id3 = b.id3
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff DOH, I don't know why I read MySQL as MSSQL! Fixed now